# Thread-safe network stream freezes the thread who call it's Close() method

Tags: c#, multithreading, stream

A thread-safe stream from `WebResponse.GetResponseStream()` is passed to another thread which will read the `stream` to the end and `Close()` it. `stream.synchronized()` is used for stream thread safety:

```
// Thread A
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse(); 
return Stream.Synchronized(response.GetResponseStream());

// Thread B
// Read the stream to the end
stream.Close(); // Here thread doesn't get back
```

Thread B is under control of another thread which is not the subject of this question (thread C). Only thing about thread C is if thread B doesn't exit properly it will `Abort()` thread B. The problem is Thread B freezes at `stream.Close()` and it's always aborted by thread C. Whatever the timeout (a waithandle with timeout is used) I set, thread B will not pass that line and during the timeout period CPU is 100%

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: The static method `Stream.Synchronized` wraps any std stream as thread-safe as `MSDN` says.

Comment: if the stream is not being used concurrently (two threads simultaneously accessing the object) that isn't needed. A non-synchronised stream can be used by different threads, just ensure it is one thread at a time.

Comment: why are you creating a thread-safe stream anyway - from pseudo code, it appears that the stream will be used by one thread at a time?

Comment: I always get nervous about a method when I search and find few examples of its use...

Comment: @Richard: I've tried both thread-safe and non-thread-safe versions but the result is the same. Without closing the stream CPU remains at 100% and if I close it the thread who has closed it should be aborted.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest starting with something like [TCP/View](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897437) to find the state of the underlying stream—is the other end not allowing it to clean up cleanly? Or do you need to set socket options to close more quickly?

A workaround might be to allow the `Close` to happen in the thread pool, or allow the GC to put the unclosed stream into the finalisation queue.

Comment: I just want to do it safely. I tried to comment out the `stream.close()` method but again CPU gets 100% and even with the thread abortion never come down so I should kill `w3wp.exe` manually !

Comment: @Xaqron: Based on comments on the Q: try removing the synchronisation wrapper. If `w3wp.exe` is running in a tight loop then a few sample breaks into the debugger (or from core dumps) and looking at the stack traces should give you information (this will require gaining some understanding of the Win32 API). Also try stripping this down to a re-create with everything else removed -- the stream *might* be a red herring.

Comment: By you good debugging idea SOLVED. The problem was inside the `Dispose()` method of stream container object. In fact I was calling `stream.Close()` twice. But still wondering why I cannot put another `stream.Close()` inside the `Dispose() method for safety !

Comment: @ Xaqron: if Richard's answer helped you, I suggest you accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `request.Abort()` before `stream.Close()` if nothing else helping you.